# Why does my object change it appearance when moving camera

Tags: mesh, camera

I made a bookshelf and used 3 meshes for different books. The other two are looking fine though and i all seamed them the same way and made them out of cubes.

[image]

This one blue book though keeps acting weird. Each time i move the camera it doesnt show the front of the mesh.
What did i possibly do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normals are inverted and backface culling is enabled.

Recalculate the normal by going into edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: Oops, clicked on ok, but wasnt done.

Comment: Again :p
One more question. I use this mesh to duplicate so i would have the same textures in multiple books. Is it ok if i just tab -> CTRL+N one by one. Would it mess up the duplicated meshes and their texture?

Comment: Either way, the duplicates / same textured objects will be fine. You can do them one by one.